# AWS or Google for a dedicated compute node

Tags: amazon-web-services, cloud, virtualhost, google-cloud-platform

I have just started to look at cloud services and pricing. AWS seems to offer more options for creating instances. But I still don't know what is suitable for me, so I am just reaching you guys for an opinion. What I require is to have:
 1 single **physical** core (ideally high speed), 256 GB of RAM, and 3 TB of **dedicated** disk space. So I basically need a physical server (no shared hardware with other users) with these resources. The issue I have with the current service providers is that they don't provide physical cpu core, and it's often unclear whether the disk is shared or it's dedicated. I am going to use this for benchmarking a few programs against mine, on large amount of data and these programs are sensitive to I/O access, hence I need everything to be dedicated and not shared to get a fair comparison.

Comment: "so I am just reaching you guys for an opinion" that makes the question off topic for this site. Also if you want to lease **physical** compute hardware then cloud computing services like AWS and Google probably aren't right for you.

Comment: @MarkB yeah I was expecting down-vote, etc. Are you aware of any service that provides dedicated instances?

Comment: You need to do a Google search for "lease dedicated server" instead of looking at Google/AWS/Azure which are very different services from what you are looking for.

Answer (score 1):

The whole idea of cloud computing is to share resources so indeed most of the offers will be with sharing services.

Amazon quite recently open a new service which will be a good fit for you : https://aws.amazon.com/ec2/dedicated-hosts/

I am not clear if GCE has the same but I dont think so.

I dont know what you want to do with that so I will leave it to your own benchmark to see if its worth it or not

Comment: Is there another service provider that you suggest? I checked Microsoft Azure, but it's very expensive ...

Comment: dedicated instance is gonna be expensive, specially with your spec ... its not usual that you can adjust the hard drive up to 3 TB so easily, many of the vendors go for fast SSD drive but then limit the size. still https://aws.amazon.com/ec2/dedicated-hosts/ could be a good fit